# SDL2 program crashes in 64bit mode but works fine in 32bit (compiled using cmake and mingw32-make)

Tags: c, cmake, sdl-2, mingw32

cmake works just fine (I guess! I just started using cmake) with no error so does mingw32-make. I suppose compilation and linking is done correctly. But when I open the program (graphics.exe) it immediately stops working. (BTW I'm not missing SDL2.dll) whats wrong?

edit:
It works just fine when using 32bit libraries and 32bit dll and "-m32". BUT it crashes when using 64bit stuff.

CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(graphics)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
set(DEPS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Deps)

include_directories("${DEPS}/include")

add_executable(graphics ${SOURCE_FILES})
#find sdl2 libraries
find_library(SDL2MAIN_LIB SDL2main ${DEPS}/lib)
find_library(SDL2_LIB SDL2 ${DEPS}/lib)

message("SDL2main found at: ${SDL2MAIN_LIB}")
message("SDL2 found at: ${SDL2_LIB}")

target_link_libraries(graphics ${SDL2MAIN_LIB})
target_link_libraries(graphics ${SDL2_LIB})
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
        printf("SDL2 up and running\n");
    else
        printf("Could not initialize SDL2");
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you say "stops working" what do you mean by that? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: oh, I mean that windows thing that pops up and says - in my case- graphics.exe has stopped working

Comment: No exception messages?

Comment: @JeroenHeier no nothing

Comment: @user3877946 good time to start using debugger. There may be any number of reasons, including usage of wrong dll (e.g. msvc built instead of mingw).

Comment: @keltar It works fine when I use the 32bit libs and dll and -m32 as "CMAKE_C_FLAG", but it crashes when using 64bit